# Jquery Datatable selecting colums from dropdown

Tags: datatables

I am planning to use Jquery datatable.
I want to select many columns and enable user to select which column to display.

I have found this,
https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html

But what i want is that toggle line to be a dropdown. How can i do this?
Or is there any other plugin which supports this.???

Comment: so you want Dropdowns for each column (e.g in your example there are 5 columns like  Name - Position - Office - Age - Start date - Salary) ? Can you draw some UI (in mspaint or some other software) which can help in visualizing what exactly you want ?

Comment: Or, @vibs2006, is a multi-select what is required here?

Comment: @annoyingmouse yes Multi-select would be a better choice. I guess question is not correctly framed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example [here](http://live.datatables.net/winuqefi/1/edit). It's creating the dropdown `select` element which will toggle the visibility of the column selected.

The code is:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

  table.columns().every(function(index, tableCounter, counter) {
    $('<option/>').val(counter).text($('#example thead th:eq(' + counter + ')').text()).appendTo('#select');    
  });

  $('#select').on('change', function() {
    var visible = table.column($(this).val()).visible();
    table.column($(this).val()).visible(!visible);
  });
} );
```